# Azure ML studio web service output

Tags: jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service

I made a web service from a python notebook and the output is:

```
{"Results":{"output1":{"type":"table","value":{"Values":[["1"]]}},"output2":{"type":"table","value":{"Values":[["data:text/plain,Execution OK\r\n",null]]}}}}
```

But I just wanted the response to be the value in the key "Values" so that way I don't have to parse it on the client side. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think you can change the response it sends to you. You can tell it what columns to return from it, but that's about it.

Comment: I thought that would be the problem. Thank you :) @Jon